# Javascript errors, uncaught type error

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying out a theme, which uses masonry. When I uploaded it to my server I am getting 5 errors in the dev tool. I'm at a loss as I'm clueless with the backend stuff.

Here is the link to the site: http://stevengeorgeharris.com/kevin/ and below is my problem.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) http://stevengeorgeharris.com/kevin/wp-content/themes/imbalance22/libs/jquery-ui.custom.min.js?ver=3.5.1
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) http://stevengeorgeharris.com/kevin/wp-content/themes/imbalance22  /libs/jquery.infinitescroll.min.js?ver=3.5.1
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) http://stevengeorgeharris.com/kevin/wp-content/themes/imbalance22/libs/jquery.masonry.min.js?ver=3.5.1
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function stevengeorgeharris.com:49
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function stevengeorgeharris.com:355

Comment: We can't see what the cause of the 500 is -- probably in your server logs

Comment: Your 500 is generated because it's looking in the `imbalance22` folder for your javascript files, yet your actual folder has a space in it (`imbalance2 2`). Remove the space in your folder name.

Comment: I uploaded an un-edited version of the theme, which has now got rid of the 500 but not the uncaught TypeError. @ExplosionPills

Comment: @ChristianVarga thank you! that makes sense. I still have the uncaught TypeError though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `$` use `jQuery`.  You could also do:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
```

and refer to the variable as `$` in that scope.

Comment: Thank you! That worked a charm, will I run in to anymore problems or is that all I need to change?

Comment: @Steven_Harris_ you should be okay as long as *all* of your code is within the `.ready` function

Answer (score 3):

You're using jQuery in compatibility mode.

When you use it like that, jQuery is not define as "$" (because other frameworks like to use this var name).

You should change your jQuery file or simply use this piece of code:

```
var $ = jQuery;
```

You can also use "jQuery" instead of "$".